# Controle de Estoque Agrupando Produtos do mesmo tipo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lógica, e-commerce

Estou produzindo um sistema de controle de estoque, porém o estoque precisa ter um sistema de agrupamento de produtos com o mesmo SKU, exemplo, eu tenho um produto que se chama "Camiseta A", porém existem varios tipos de "Camisetas A", tenho os tamanhos diferentes, porém agrupando por SKU.

Como eu poderia fazer isso de forma a não comprometer o controle?

Ex: Quando sair um produto com SKU "sk001" de tamanho "M" não influenciar no controle do estoque dos produtos com SKU "sk001" de tamanho "G".

Comment: Porque não cria uma tabela focado em castro de SKU e uma pra relacionar os dois? assim você vai ter o sistema funcionando e vai conseguir ter o agrupamento por SKU

Comment: Só pra eu entender melhor, antes de responder, SKU é uma espécie de categoria onde o varios itens tem o mesmo SKU, correto ?

Comment: De que forma? Poderia me dar um exemplo disso? Como se na hora que eu fosse mostrar os produtos na tela, eu buscasse todos os SKU dando um join na tabela de produtos (e ai la com os respectivos atributos?). Mas ai como ficaria na tabela de lançamentos? Porque eu preciso registrar os produtos que estão saindo, certo?

Comment: na verdade SKU é uma especie de identificação do produto dentro do estoque, é tipo o ID, exemplo, eu tenho la Camisa A, tamanho P, sku 'aaabr22', ai eu teria la camisa A, tamanho M, SKU 'aaabr22' e assim vai

Comment: https://uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/v2/loja-virtual/o-que-e-sku-de-um-produto-da-minha-loja-virtual.html#rmcl 

Aqui explica melhor

Comment: Sim eu li, o SKU é basicamente um uuid, no seu exemplo e divergente, mas podemos fazer o que falei atrelar um id SKU a um item de estoque, a quando buscar pelo sku em questão via ver todos os itens / movimentação. esse sistema é só de controle de estoque ? tem controle de notas ou algo a mais ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88503/discussion-between-hanania-mizrahi-and-bulfaitelo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, vamos a solução que discutimos no chat, resolvemos mudar um pouco a estrutura do projeto.

Aonde iremos adicionar o campo de tamanhos se relacionado as categorias dos produtos, assim ao castrar uma movimentação ele automaticamente irá carregar os possíveis tamanhos, para que na hora do cadastro de alguma movimentação de estoque não ocorra problemas, e com essa alteração funcione conforme o necessário para o controle do estoque.

[**chat**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88503/) Para mais informações recomendo a leitura do chat